# Allow the Gallery to retrive all items from SharePoint using paging if the Items for the gallery is based on nested Collections

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, power-platform

We have the following SharePoint list which contains around 2,800 items:-

[image]

then inside Power Apps we added a gallery with the following source:-

[image]

and inside the screen onvisible, we added the following formula, to show all items group by GrantTitle:-

```
ClearCollect(colSource,Filter('Grant Applications', CurrentState="1" || CurrentState="0"));

// Create a collection of all daily appointments
ClearCollect(
    colGrants,
    AddColumns(
        ShowColumns(colSource
           ,
            "ID",
            "GrantTitle",
            "Grantee",
            "GrantAmount"
        ),
        "Level",
        2
    )
);
// Create a collection of all unique Title values
 ClearCollect(
     colGrantTitles,
     AddColumns(
         RenameColumns(
             Distinct(
                 colSource,
                 GrantTitle
             ),
             "Result",
             "GrantTitle"
         ).GrantTitle,
         "Level",
         1
     )
 );
// Combine both collections into a single collection
ClearCollect(
    colCombinedGrants,
    colGrants,
    colGrantTitles
);
//// *** NEW CODE ****
// Sort the combined collection
ClearCollect(
    colSortedGrants,
    SortByColumns(
        colCombinedGrants,
        "GrantTitle",
        "GrantAmountRequested_x0028_inUSD",
        "Level"
    )
);
```

now inside the screen i added a label to show the items count inside gallery as follow':-

```
CountRows(Gallery1.AllItems )
```

and when the screen is loaded it will show only 2038 items as follow:-

[image]

and even if i scroll down no more items will be shown.. so how i can fix this issue? to allow the galley to show all the items when we scroll down to the end?

Also i changed the server-side item count to be 2,000:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you need to take care of.

1. [Delegation in PowerApps (Canvas App)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview)
   Your filter operator is delegtion operator i.e it will give you result based on first 2k records only and not your complete SP list records.
2. once you avoid delegation on filter, make sure you do the same in your other code as well.
3. Before you do all these collection and so on, simply take the SP list as it is and see if you get your desired 2.8k records (you should when you keep scrolling)

Comment: but the issue is that i will not be able to group the item by Title inside a Canvas without using collections